# How can I get "lowercase" namespace with cls.__members__ to work?

Tags: python, enums, enum-flags

## So I have written this module:

### **plaform.py**

```
from enum import IntFlag

class PlatformFlag(IntFlag):
    LINUX = 1,
    MACOSX = 2,
    WINDOWS = 3
globals().update(PlatformFlag.__members__)
```

### **And I am trying to use it this way:**

```
import platform

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if platform.WINDOWS:
        print("This is Windows!")
```

However, I get:

**"Exception has occurred: AttributeError module 'platform' has no attribute 'WINDOWS'"**

### **This works:**

```
import platform

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if platform.PlatformFlag.WINDOWS:
        print("This is Windows!")
```

However, **this is NOT the desired way of doing it**. I am thinking about the **re.py** in cPython. They way you can invoke this e.g. **re.compile(pattern, flags=re.M)**. However, for some reason unknown to me, the **globals().upate()** doesn't seem to do the trick, or I am missing something here.

### **Re.py:**

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/re.py

EDIT: This deserves credit, https://repl.it/@JoranBeasley/IntentionalPastStrategies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you have comes from naming, as there is a builtin module called platform.

https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/platform.html

Running your code with another name like platform123.py works. However the functionality to determine which OS is running is not part of your code and as such does not work :)

The way RE works is by taking the flags as input to the functions. The globals().update(xx.__members__) only makes the members of the classes available in the global namespace so you can use platform.WINDOWS instead of platform.PlatformFlag.WINDOWS.

Comment: @SimonF, thanks for the update! But I keep getting: Module 'p' has no 'WINDOWS' memberpylint(E1101), why do I get this?

Comment: @JohnSmith pylint probable doesn't realise that you change the global namespace dynamically. However the code runs and behaves as expected.

Comment: @SimonF, Yes, it does indeed work! Thanks a lot for clarifying this to me.

Comment: @JohnSmith No problem! To see the members of an object you can use print(dir(p))